# JavaScript FreeCodeCamp Palindrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, palindrome

I wrote the following code to check for a palindrome in JS. I can't get the following strings to work:

```
palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym.")
palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama")
```

I don't understand why. I understand there are more simple methods but I want to understand why this in particular isn't working. Here is the code:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  //gets rid of all special characters, turns string to lowercase
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  //turns string into an array of characters, including whitespaces
  array = str.split("");
  //removes white space in the array
  array = array.filter(function(val) {
    return /\S/.test(val);
  });
  //defines new variable for the length of the array
  var length = array.length;
  //while loop to cycle through the array. Originally used zero, but I realized that wouldnt work for an odd-
  // numbered array. takes off the first and last value and compares them. If they are not equal, returns 
  // false. 
  while (length > 1) {
    var a = array.shift();
    var b = array.pop();
    length = array.length; //sets new length

    if (a != b) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym."))
console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"))
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean?

Comment: A few `console.log()` statements to debug the process would have revealed the problem pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You're eliminating UPPER CASE characters before you lower case the string.

For example: "A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
```

We now have: "manaplanacanalanama" - because you've said "kill of anything that isn't lower case or a number. Oops.

Change the order to this and it will work!

```
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't catch this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your first regex is case sensitive and only matches lowercase letters, so you are stripping out all the capital letters.

Fixed by adding one character:

(alternatively, you could move the `.toLowerCase()` line up before using the regex)

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  //gets rid of all special characters, turns string to lowercase
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig, '');
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  //turns string into an array of characters, including whitespaces
  array = str.split("");
  //removes white space in the array
  array = array.filter(function(val) {
    return /\S/.test(val);
  });
  //defines new variable for the length of the array
  var length = array.length;
  //while loop to cycle through the array. Originally used zero, but I realized that wouldnt work for an odd-
  // numbered array. takes off the first and last value and compares them. If they are not equal, returns 
  // false. 
  while (length > 1) {
    var a = array.shift();
    var b = array.pop();
    length = array.length; //sets new length

    if (a != b) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym."));
console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"));
console.log(palindrome('Ada'));
console.log(palindrome('Dada'));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You first remove non-lower-alphanumeric characters before you lower-case the string. Swap those two lines so you first convert the string to all lower-case characters, then remove non-alphanumerics.
2. Since you already removed characters that aren't `a-z` or `0-9`, you don't have to account for whitespace at all! This means you can remove your `filter()`, which does nothing in this case.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  //gets rid of all special characters, turns string to lowercase
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');

  array = str.split("");
  //defines new variable for the length of the array
  var length = array.length;
  //while loop to cycle through the array. Originally used zero, but I realized that wouldnt work for an odd-
  // numbered array. takes off the first and last value and compares them. If they are not equal, returns 
  // false. 
  while (length > 1) {
    var a = array.shift();
    var b = array.pop();
    length = array.length; //sets new length

    if (a != b) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym."))
console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"))
```

Comment: Nice catch. Was just testing that and removing it when you commented ;)

Answer (score 0):

Move the string to lowercase above the replace and try again.

```
function palindrome(str) {
  //gets rid of all special characters, turns string to lowercase
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
    //turns string into an array of characters, including whitespaces
    array = str.split("");
    //removes white space in the array
    array = array.filter(function(val) {
      return /\S/.test(val);
    });
    //defines new variable for the length of the array
    var length = array.length;
    //while loop to cycle through the array. Originally used zero, but I                         realized that wouldnt work for an odd-
    // numbered array. takes off the first and last value and compares them. If they are not equal, returns
    // false.
    while (length > 1) {
      var a = array.shift();
      var b = array.pop();
      length = array.length; //sets new length

      if (a != b) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  console.log(palindrome("My age is 0, 0 si ega ym."))
  console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"))
```